# Scala: Get value from list

Tags: scala, gatling

I am trying to get a random id item from this session array for the payload:

```
.payload{session => 
  session("ids").as[Array[String]](random.nextInt(
    session("ids").as[Array[String]].length))}
```

This is not working because I cannot get something from the array once I write .as[Array].

I have to use session object in this way, and when I do anything like the following example, it fails because the code isn't synchronous:

```
.payload{session => {
  val data = session("ids").as[Array[String]]
  data(random.nextInt(data.length))
}}
```

How can I get a value from session("ids") in one line, synchronously?

Comment: Not sure to understand why you talk about synchronicity here. What error do you get in each case?

Comment: Same here (Gatling creator here). Your assumptions about synchronicity here are wrong. Please elaborate.

Comment: For example, when I try this code:
```Random.shuffle(session("ids").as[Array[String]].toList).head```
It prints out the entire array of ids, instead of taking the head id. This made me think that I am not understanding how this runs synchronously.

Comment: I mean that the script is printing the array to the console, and the request that I am testing is never actually making the request.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `data` in a call that's processed as Gatling EL, you can just use`#{data.random()}`